# Downgrading a SSL-cert SHA-2 to SHA-1

Tags: https, centos, sha1, sha, sha2

Yes, I need to downgrade to SHA-1 to add compatibility to older browser in a project.

Is there a way to do this?
I'm using Linux Centos 6.5 and Apache/2.2.15.

I have 3 files:

- SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/portal.crt
- SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/portal.key
- SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

Thanks a lot for any support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-issue the certificate (if it's self-signed) or request the re-issue from the CA if it has been obtained from the CA.